# how to run Audio from IPython.display on a notebook using a python file?

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a python project with a python file called my_audio.py

The code inside it is like this:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
...
Audio(audio_array, rate=SAMPLE_RATE)
```

when I run this code on a notebook, for example on Google Colab, it works fine:
[image]

But when I try to run the code using the python file, it doesn't show the audio generated like the above picture:

```
!python my_audio.py
```

It processes the code, but there's no audio generated, so it seems that the Audio module only run on an interactive environement like a notebook, so is there a way to make this work even with a python file ?